# How to programatically add LinearLayout object to my context?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have my app, it has the following appareance:

[image]

The table at the bottom side is a TableLayout.
In my MainActivity.java I am using the following code to populate the whole layout of my app:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

movieCompletionView = (TokenCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.searchMovie);
cineCompletionView = (TokenCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.searchCine);
...          
TableLayout tl_Movies = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutMovies);

tl_Movies.removeAllViews();

for (...) tl_Movies.addView(someRow);
```

Then, I googled for some samples to improve the appareance of my table, and I found this:

[image]

But this sample builds only the table. In the MainActivity.java the code used for building it :

```
Table table = new Table(this);
setContentView(table);
```

And Table class:

```
public class Table extends LinearLayout {
..
}
```

Now, what I want is to add the smarter table to the original layout of my app.

I added an empty LinearLayout component in my activity_main.xml and I tried to populate it with this code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

movieCompletionView = (TokenCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.searchMovie);
cineCompletionView = (TokenCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.searchCine);
...

linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.smarterTable);
linearLayout = new Table(this);
```

But it does not work.
Sorry for the very basic question, but, can you tell me which are the right statements for adding the smarter table to the original layout of my app?

**Edit 27-Nov-2017**

Following the suggestion on Mike M. and F43nd1r.

I configured my activity_main.xml in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.myapps.pavel.myseapp.MainActivity">

    <com.myapps.pavel.myseapp.Table
        android:id="@+id/smarterTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I used the following code in my MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    linearLayout = (Table) findViewById(R.id.smarterTable);
```

And I got this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapps.pavel.myseapp, PID: 5875
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapps.pavel.myseapp/com.myapps.pavel.myseapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.myapps.pavel.myseapp.Table
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.myapps.pavel.myseapp.Table
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.myapps.pavel.myseapp.Table
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:618)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.myapps.pavel.myseapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83) /* This lane has this statement: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);*/
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

**Solved!**:

as Mike M. says, I had to change the parameters of the Table constructor

```
public Table(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
```

[image]

Comment: Don't add an empty `<LinearLayout>` to your layout. Add a `<com.mycompany.myapp.Table>`, for example, and find that. (Do note that you have to use the fully qualified class name in the `Table` tag, substituting your package for the `com.mycompany.myapp`.) You then won't need `new Table(this)` at all in your Java code.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my post using your solution.

Comment: The `Table` must have a `public` constructor that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`. Have a look at the top answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312581) for an example, if ya need. Do note that you'll also need to perform any necessary initializations in that new constructor, too.

Comment: Wonderfull!! It Works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<LinearLayout>` use `<com.your.package.Table>` in the xml layout.

Then use the following:

```
linearLayout = (Table) findViewById(R.id.smarterTable);
for (...) linearLayout.addView(someRow);
```

---

### Edit regarding your edit

Add this constructor to Table:

```
public Table(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```