# Remove View from Custom Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

Continuing with my previous question: [How to programatically add LinearLayout object to my context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501935/how-to-programatically-add-linearlayout-object-to-my-context?noredirect=1#comment81990929_47501935)

I have my app with this appareance:

[image]

This is the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:text="Movies : "
            .../>

        <com.myapps.pavel.myseapp.TokenCompletionView
            android:id="@+id/searchMovie"
            ... />

        ...

    </LinearLayout>


    <com.myapps.pavel.myseapp.Table
        android:id="@+id/smarterTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how my MainActivity.java starts:

```
Table tl_Movies;
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

movieCompletionView = (TokenCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.searchMovie);
movieCompletionView.setTokenListener( new TokenCompleteTextView.TokenListener(){        
    tl_Movies = (Table) findViewById(R.id.smarterTable); 
    tl_Movies.createTestData(els_items); //Get filtered data
    tl_Movies.loadData();//Load filtered data into table
})

...
tl_Movies = (Table) findViewById(R.id.smarterTable);    
tl_Movies.createTestData(els_items); //Get whole data
tl_Movies.loadData();//Load whole data into table
```

However, when I select any choice on the filters, **all the "new" records are appended at the end of the table**.

So, for "cleaning" the table before to rebuild it I use this on both sides (in event and at start):

```
tl_Movies = (Table) findViewById(R.id.smarterTable);
tl_Movies.removeAllViews();
tl_Movies.createTestData(els_items);
tl_Movies.loadData();
```

However, using this, the table does not appear at all from the begining. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

This is where i got the Table class:
http://justsimpleinfo.blogspot.com.es/2015/04/android-scrolling-table-with-fixed.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate view after remove view  like below

```
    tl_Movies.invalidate();
```

Comment: I use this: 

`tl_Movies = (Table) findViewById(R.id.smarterTable);
tl_Movies.removeAllViews();
tl_Movies.invalidate();
tl_Movies.createTestData(els_items);
tl_Movies.loadData();`

But the output is the same.. the table does not appear at all.